# How to Initialize my UITableView table to have a certain number of rows based on input from user and a Button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm really new to Objective-C here so what I'm asking may be trivial to most of you but any guidance will help.
Here's a picture of my storyboad.

[image]

My current objective is to allow for the user to enter in the number of sets (NSInteger *numReps) and then press the "Log Reps" button and have the table initialize with numReps cells that look like the prototype cell.

Now where I'm at a loss for the implementation.  I've never done this kind of thing before so I'm not exactly sure what the best way to go about it is.  I have thought of making a custom class for the UITableView table that would take info from the view after the Log Reps button is pushed.  I'm not entirely sure how this would need to be implemented.  Or can I simply add the table to the properties of the view controller and setup the table within the view controller?  That was my initial idea and seems ideal so that I would have everything in one place.

Pleas advise.  I am new to all of this and come from a C++ background so I'm still learning a lot of the notation.

Comment: Do you want to allow reps only or reps and weight?  From the looks of your storyboard, you may want to think about the design a bit more before you start coding (It's awesome to see someone doing a workout app).

Comment: I will implement the weight after I figure out how to do this.  Trying to take it one step at a time :)

Comment: As everyone mentioned below, you'll have to hook into the table view delegate and data source methods.  If you can figure out how to set your viewcontroller as the delegate and data source, all the methods you'll need start with tableview.  The auto-complete should help.  I found building views with xibs a bit limiting.  I do however like to use xibs for table cells.  The number of rows that appear is based on a table view delegate method (see below answers).  Whenever the user hits enter, add that number of sets to your data source.  Then call reload on your table view.  This will refresh it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  -(IBAction)btnLogClicked {
        int iSet = 4 //Number of row in table
        UITableView *tblView= [[UITab;eView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,320,100)];
        tblView.delegate = self;
        tblView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubView:tblView];
```

}
Table View Data Source and Delegate Methods

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        return iSet;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        // Display what you want to display in each cell

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to present in your prototype cells, but you need an array (or probably an array of dictionaries) to populate the cells. The number of rows is determined by the number of entires (the count) of that array. So, if you take the number entered by the user, and add that many object to your array, then call reloadData on the table, you will get the number of rows that you want. What those object are that you add to the array, depends on what you're trying to show there.

Answer (score 0):

you could start reading: [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

But I can answer you:

You can add the `UITableView` to the `UIViewController`, but you need set your `UIViewController` like the TableView's delegate and dataSource. Your ViewController need to implement the protocol: `UITableViewDataSource`

The method that you are looking for is: `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

But I really recommend you that read the Apple Reference.